# Angular 2 EXCEPTION: The selector "app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular

Chrome DevTools is giving me the following exception when I attempt to run my very basic Angular 2 code:

> *EXCEPTION: The selector "app" did not match any elements*

The three relevant files are:

(1) **boot.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

(2) **app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {PuzzleComponent} from "./puzzle/puzzle.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <my-puzzle></my-puzzle>
        `,
    directives: [PuzzleComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

(3)  **puzzle.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-puzzle',
    template: `
        Random text
        `
})
export class PuzzleComponent{

}
```

I've confirmed that my development workspace is fine; other code works as expected.  This is for the Udemy course *The Complete Guide to Angular 2*, and I've typed in the code a couple of times trying to catch any typos.  Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Is there a main HTML file that you haven't included in your question?

Comment: It looks fine. how about your `index.html`? show us here.

Comment: TS files looks fine. Need see how do you reference the boot.ts and use the 'app' tag in main html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your body element needs to contain `<app></app>`

```
<body>
  <app></app>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, I had the opening tag in my index.html file as my-app and the closing tag as app - thanks!

Comment: without having <body> element my custom component names were not working! whoa!!

Answer (score 0):

sure you use app-routing module and must change the
selector: 'app' to 'app-root'
**app.component.ts:**

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
```